# What do i have to put in ( action=“?” )

Tags: html

Does anybody knows what I have to put in the action to get this contract full to my E-Mail?

```
<form method="post" name="contact" action="#">

    <label for="fullname">Name:</label> 
    <input name="fullname" type="text" class="required input_field" id="fullname" maxlength="40" />
    <div class="cleaner h10"></div> 

    <label for="email">Email:</label> 
    <input name="email" type="text" class="validate-email required input_field" id="email" maxlength="40" /> 
    <div class="cleaner h10"></div> 

    <label for="subject">Betreff:</label> 
    <input name="subject" type="text" class="validate-subject required input_field" id="subject" maxlength="60"/> 
    <div class="cleaner h10"></div> 

    <label for="message">Nachricht:</label> 
    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="0" cols="0" class="required"></textarea> 
    <div class="cleaner h10"></div>                

    <input type="submit" value="Senden" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" /> 
    <input type="reset" value="Zur&uuml;cksetzten" id="reset" name="reset" class="submit_btn float_r" /> 

</form>
```

Comment: You put in the path and file name of the script that will process it, or leave it blank to have it post back to the same page which should process it.

Comment: I can't believe this isn't explained in every single tutorial on writing web forms. Shouldn't you learn the basics before coming here with questions?

Answer (score 0):

Path to filename that will handle the request or blank if it will be handled right on the page where the form is.
Try looking for web form example + your severside language of choice.
I.e. http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
action="mailto:your@mail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain"
```